# How to properly type the intersection of interfaces extending from Record<>?

Tags: typescript, interface

It was supposed to be straightforward... I've broken down my problem to the barest, minimum code to reproduce my issue

First define a type with the general shape of all records

```
type BaseRecord = Record<string, number|string>
```

Then define the specific record interfaces

```
interface RecordA extends BaseRecord {}

interface RecordB extends BaseRecord {}
```

Next define the shape of the final document which is composed of a `RecordA` and a collection of `RecordB`

```
interface Collection {
    bees: RecordB[]
}

type WithCollection = RecordA & Collection
```

Finally, compose the document

```
declare const a: RecordA
declare const c: Collection
const d: WithCollection = {...a, ...c}
```

Here, the last line above fails with `Type ... is not assignable to type ...` when assigning `d`

If I drop the `extends BaseRecord` from RecordA, the error goes away (as well as the benefits from extending from BaseRecord).

The actual code is in fact more complex with BaseRecord having advanced types for values, while RecordA and RecordB have dozens of attributes.

Here is a [playground reproducing the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIHEFMDtoE4EMA24DOALJAHa4AzAewXFTQWgGMSATdcEYAKABcBPPcAISXWgBK1OuAC84ITQS0APOlYIAlrADmAGnCwArgFsARogA%208paoB8zZsGDhWmfAANoAD1Zx6D8EViaXrcCjK%20HqUSADWDHb4RHoAVtT%20tNAmWqYqwOg4obRePih8rP6B8OAA3szKbggESFT4knQAguB%207gy8-A3SZQC%20VjaViDV1EsLSzaV9-bb24E6ubZ7YDLBEGIpJLQQECQzlg9W19WO03C0LsPQ8fIInvZYHw-gAwkQoKAmK3mXM4H-gBmSAC5RlJTgBtAC6zCmHC4AHVFHZXu9Pt9xF1aM0AGTgFEfKisL6wSxJKj5SjgGiweRkEGYxrMMkU-DU2lUEH4tEktmJEGI5FvAlE9FlAB0EqQGglYqofSAA)

Comment: Does `type BaseRecord = Record<string, number|string|BaseRecord[]>` suit you?

Comment: An intersection “means” that both sides are true; so `WithCollection`’s `bees` property must be both a `RecordB[]` (from `Collection`) and a `number|string` (from `RecordA`), which is not possible. If that’s not what you mean, then the `Collection` type might not be the right thing for you.  There are no official “hybrid” index types (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867 ) so you want to refactor or work around it

Comment: Actually no. BaseRecord describes the shapes of complex objects (pulled  from a database) which do not have collections and is defined in a client module which is also used in different context. Documents are produced with collections (1-N relationships) added in a specific disttinctt module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the assignment statement explicit to your intersection type:

```
type BaseRecord = Record<string, number | string>

interface RecordA extends BaseRecord { }
interface RecordB extends BaseRecord { }

interface Collection {
    bees: RecordB[]
}

type WithCollection = RecordA & Collection

const a: RecordA = { "foo": 1, "bar": "2", };
const c: Collection = { bees: [{"maya": "hello maya"}] };
const d = { ...a, ...c } as WithCollection // cast object to intersectiontype
```

Here is a running [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgJQgYwPYCcAmUC8UqmuAPAsFgJYB2A5gDRQ0CuAtgEYRZQA%20UFavQB8AKFG1g3AGZw00YthwBBKBAAeUmjgSxEKdEqgBvKAF8JNKVlnyih3DDWaI23fCSLcJ8%20Mky5aABhDAAbUPRgKgwaE1EoBKguCAQALnsSHBgAbQBdUQtRUEgoAHUqYAALEPDI6NjCLxUoADIoGoi0KJjxTBoKKDh0ptVCUwAiaQwMcfSARiZxjjgsWahxgCZxpjMAblE%20gbR0jrqYgh9ktKhs43G2OBA4NfHKiHCMKAen8bNc832h2AUDwYygADpIXAmJDwWhzINdOUqqcuvVejEEGEIODQhg6AAKHDZSbTca5ACUB0x2Nx%20KJJOWq0p1P6tLxhJw4Ku2QADLkSd9niygA) example.

Comment: Using cast operators is a cheating in 99% cases ;)

Comment: guess its the 0,1 over here

Comment: I wish there was another way and avoid casting. Perhaps WithCollection should be something more than an intersection.